# Split character vector by element in R?

Tags: r, string, vector, split

Given a vector:

```
c("kuku", "pupu", "lilu","","ff","rrrr", "", "rrr")
```

How can I split it by `""`?

To get 3 vectors:

```
c("kuku", "pupu", "lilu")
c("ff","rrrr")
c("rrr")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get the cumulative sum of logical vector to create the grouping index for `split`

```
i1 <- v1 == ""
i1
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE


grp <- cumsum(i1)
grp
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2
```

Note that with cumulative sum, it adds 1 at every TRUE value.  Then, we do a subset of the vector to not include the `""`.  By negating (`!`) the TRUE beomes FALSE and FALSE -> TRUE.

```
v1[!i1]
#[1] "kuku" "pupu" "lilu" "ff"   "rrrr" "rrr"
```

Similarly, the 'grp' is also subsetted as we want both vectors to be of the same length and do the `split`

```
split(v1[!i1], grp[!i1])
#$`0`
#[1] "kuku" "pupu" "lilu"

#$`1`
#[1] "ff"   "rrrr"

#$`2`
#[1] "rrr"
```

Comment: Dear akrun, as always brilliant answer. Please be so kind and explain a bit.

Comment: @SteveS thanks.  I added some explanation. Hope it helps